# designing graphics with new data created

Tags: r

```
 df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19- 
 timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv',
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 df6 <- aggregate(recovered ~ region, subset(df), sum)
```

I calculated the number of regions recovered.

How do I create a line chart of this data.

Comment: What exactly do you want as output? Some kind of `barplot(df6$recovered, names.arg=df6$region)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data:

```
df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19-timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df6 <- aggregate(recovered ~ region, subset(df), sum)
```

Plot in base R:

```
barplot(df6$recovered, names.arg=df6$region)
```

Plot using tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df6 %>% ggplot(aes(region, recovered)) + geom_col()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a **line** plot, you should probably keep the day variable.

```
df$day <- as.Date(df$day)
df6 <- aggregate(recovered ~ day+region, data=df, FUN=sum)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df6, aes(day, recovered, col=region)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]